# Vertical RecyclerView containing nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, nestedrecyclerview

Structure of my Android app is forcing me to create Vertical Nested RecyclerView inside Vertical Nested RecyclerView because of the pre-drawing all nested items inside every RootRecyclerView. The View of RootRecyclerView has approximately 5 - 10 views and the View of InsideRecyclerView consists also from 5-10 views. There is not necessarity for scrolling this ChildRecyclerView, because all scrolling is handled by RootRecyclerView (same term as Nested RecyclerView)

I have two options:
1. ChildRecyclerView, that will predraw all child items when the root item will reached the screen (it lags, but the result looks good under the 30 child rows)
2. Join the Root+Child View, remove Child RecyclerView and the all logic will be handled in the Root RecyclerView. - i tried this, also used ConstraintLayout, so the whole layout was only 1-LEVEL, but it was still laggy, even if I set Visibility of half of the views in this layout. I also setup setHasFixedSize(true), tried to use Cache methods of RecyclerView, initialCacheItemSize and so on.

So do you have any ideas, how to solve this problem? Did somebody of you met with this kind of problem? You could also imagine the case of ChildRecyclerView inside another ChildRecyclerView that is inside RootRecyclerView.

Comment: you can use expandable recyclerview.

Comment: @jantursky follow link https://manticarodrigo.com/nested-android-recyclerview-kotlin/